# Mutable HashMap with a mutable default value doesn't keep the changes

Tags: scala, hashmap, default-value, scala-collections, mutable

Suppose that I want a mutable `HashMap[Int, HashSet[Int]]` that has

- integers as keys
- **mutable** hash sets of integers as values

I want that an empty mutable `HashSet` is created by default whenever a value for a new key is accessed or updated.

Here is what I tried:

```
import collection.mutable.{HashMap, HashSet}

val hm = HashMap
  .empty[Int, HashSet[Int]]
  .withDefault(_ => HashSet.empty[Int])

hm(42) += 1234

println(hm)
```

The unexpected result is an empty `HashMap`. I expected a hash map with `(42 -> HashSet(1234))` key-value pair.

Why doesn't the `HashMap` save the default mutable `HashSet`s, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
hm(42) += 1234
```

will create the default value (an empty `HashSet`), then update it by adding 1234 to it, then throw it away.

---

If you want to update the `HashMap` itself, then remove the `withDefault` part from the definition, and use `getOrElseUpdate` instead:

```
hm.getOrElseUpdate(42, HashSet.empty[Int]) += 1234
```

---

Alternatively, you can leave the `withDefault` as-is, but update your hash map as follows:

```
hm(42) = (hm(42) += 1234)
```