# Illegal Inheritance with MultiMap

Tags: scala

I would like to create a MultiMap that has a class for the key and a ListBuffer for the value.

I would like to add multiple objects that extend game object into the map. Then retrieve a group of object using the key.

GameObject

```
class GameObject {

}
```

Staff

```
Staff extends GameObject {

}
```

Customer

```
Customer extends GameObject {

}
```

Example

```
// Staff extends GameObject
val staffMembers = ListBuffer[Staff](/* Add Elements*/)

// Customer extends GameObject
val customers = ListBuffer[Customer](/* Add Elements*/)

val map = new mutable.HashMap[Class[_ <: GameObject], mutable.ListBuffer[GameObject]]() with mutable.MultiMap[Class[_ <: GameObject], GameObject]

staffMembers.foreach(staff=> map.addBinding(classOf[Staff], staff))
customers.foreach(customer=> map.addBinding(classOf[Customer], customer))
```

Error

```
Error:(34, 19) illegal inheritance;
<$anon: Class[_ <: com.casinogame.gameobject.GameObject] => 
scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[com.casinogame.gameobject.GameObject] with Class[_ <: com.casinogame.gameobject.GameObject] => 
scala.collection.mutable.Set[com.casinogame.gameobject.GameObject]> inherits different type instances of trait Map:
scala.collection.mutable.Map[Class[_ <: com.casinogame.gameobject.GameObject],scala.collection.mutable.Set[com.casinogame.gameobject.GameObject]] and scala.collection.mutable.Map[Class[_ <: com.casinogame.gameobject.GameObject],scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[com.casinogame.gameobject.GameObject]]
val map = new mutable.HashMap[Class[_ <: GameObject], mutable.ListBuffer[GameObject]]() with mutable.MultiMap[Class[_ <: GameObject], GameObject]
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: First of all you shouldn’t use mutable object because it’s not recommended.

Comment: Looking at it again are you talking about the HashMap or the ListBuffers?

Comment: can you please show the structure of staff and customer?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: I'd relativize @RamanMishra's comment as follows: you shouldn't use mutable objects unless you are developing some very low-level algorithms that must be very efficient. If you don't have a written out proof that you must use a mutable data structure so that your algorithm has runtime `O(n log(n))` instead of `O(n * log(n)^2)` or something, you probably don't have a good reason to use mutable data structures. "Customers", "staff" and "casinos" don't look like the right setting for a critical low-level algorithm.

Comment: How would I deal with any new customers/staff being created? I would need to either create a whole new list each time and append it or just use a list buffer and add it to it. I would want this to be reasonably efficient as if I have thousands of customers I don't want to create a new list each time one is added or removed.

Comment: That’s what you don’t need to append which is O(n) operation you can prepend it too which is O(1) constant time complexity operation.

Comment: Why class?? GameObject wouldn’t it be better to use trait?

Comment: Isn't what you are doing equivalent to `val map = Map(classOf[Staff] -> staffMembers, classOf[Customer] -> customers)`?

Comment: GameObject is more complex than the example I have here. It needs a constructor. 
Yes it is the same as that map structure. I wanted the extra functionality of adding elements without doing the null checks etc.

Comment: I'm struggling to grasp how I could do what I want without ListBuffers. If I need to store state and the list of elements varies throughout the game how do I deal with that? I thought this would be exactly what ListBuffer is for so I can't think how I can do it without it.

Comment: You should not need null checks (using nulls in scala are an even more rare occurrence than mutable structures). Adding on the fly most likely should not be used either, but if you are set on having it for some reason, with the simple `Map` I showed above, you could just do `staffMembers += anotherMember`, and it will show up in the `Map`(it is actually more a bad thing than a good thing - that's why people generally avoid mutable state - but will do what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the documentation more closely, and replace the nested `ListBuffer`s by ordinary mutable `Set`s, it compiles just fine:

```
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import collection.mutable.{Set, MultiMap, HashMap}

class GameObject {

}

class Staff extends GameObject {

}

class Customer extends GameObject {

}

// Staff extends GameObject
val staffMembers = ListBuffer[Staff](new Staff)

// Customer extends GameObject
val customers = ListBuffer[Customer](new Customer)

val map = 
  new HashMap[Class[_ <: GameObject], Set[GameObject]] 
  with MultiMap[Class[_ <: GameObject], GameObject]

staffMembers.foreach(staff=> map.addBinding(classOf[Staff], staff))
customers.foreach(customer=> map.addBinding(classOf[Customer], customer))
```

That being said, I think the following code snippet is closer to your original intention:

```
val map2 = HashMap.empty[Class[_ <: GameObject], ListBuffer[GameObject]]

for (s <- staffMembers) {
  map2.getOrElseUpdate(classOf[Staff], ListBuffer.empty) += s
}
for (c <- customers) {
  map2.getOrElseUpdate(classOf[Customer], ListBuffer.empty) += c
}
```

If you wrap it into a `Builder` for `Casino`s, and don't let the mutable state escape in all directions after the `Casino` is constructed, it might even be considered reasonably idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm unable to test it right now but can this evening. 
Out of curiosity what happens if no entry exists in the HashMap when adding to it in your last example? Normally you would have to check if the key exists, if so then add to the entry. If the key doesn't exist you would create a new entry.

Comment: @Michael Updated, added `withDefault`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't think it works, even with the correction: `.withDefault` returns an empty list for missing keys, but does not add it to the map, it remains empty.

Comment: @Dima Oh God, not [THIS AGAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099989/mutable-hashmap-with-a-mutable-default-value-doesnt-keep-the-changes)! Good catch! :D If even writing it down as a Q/A for myself didn't help, then I'll probably forget it again. I just don't use mutable lists in mutable hash maps all that often...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need `MultiMap`, but this will create a simple `HashMap` that maps class to values:

```
val map = HashMap(List(
  classOf[Staff] -> staffMembers,
  classOf[Customer] -> customers
):_*)
```

This also allows you to use an immutable `Map` if the set of classes is fixed at compile time.